# "ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 435: mkdir(): Permission denied" error on Goddady live hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am working on laravel project I have created a controller through store method I have inserted the form data into the database and store project picture into the location **/home/domain/public/images/projects/1st project/imgName**
but it gives me the following error. could you guys help me. **One more thing code is working fine at local Xampp server**.

**Current PHP Version 5.6 on Godday hosting**

```
> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 435:
mkdir(): Permission denied
in Filesystem.php line 435
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'mkdir(): Permission denied', '/home/vertexmarketing/public_html/beta/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php', 435, array('path' => '/images/projects/1st project/', 'mode' => 511, 'recursive' => true, 'force' => false))
at mkdir('/images/projects/1st project/', 511, true) in Filesystem.php line 435
at Filesystem->makeDirectory('/images/projects/1st project/', 511, true) in Facade.php line 221
at Facade::__callStatic('makeDirectory', array('/images/projects/1st project/', 511, true)) in ProjectController.php line 89
at File::makeDirectory('/images/projects/1st project/', 511, true) in ProjectController.php line 89
at ProjectController->store(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ProjectController), 'store'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(ProjectController), 'store') in Route.php line 204
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 160
at Route->run() in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

//validate the data
$this->validate($request, [
'name' => 'required|max:50',
'type' => 'required|max:50',
'contract' => 'required|max:50',
'city' => 'required|max:50',
'location' => 'required|max:250',
'bathrooms' => 'required|max:50',
'bedrooms' => 'required|max:50',
'garages' => 'required|max:50',            
'area' => 'required|max:50',
'price' => 'required|max:50',
'installmentplan' => 'required|max:50'


]);

//Store into the database 

$project = new projects;

$project->name = $request->name;
$project->description = $request->description;
$project->type = $request->type;
$project->contract = $request->contract;
$project->city = $request->city;
$project->location = $request->location;
$project->bathrooms = $request->bathrooms;
$project->bedrooms = $request->bedrooms;
$project->garages = $request->garages;
$project->area = $request->area;
$project->price = $request->price;
$project->installmentplan = $request->installmentplan;

if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
# code...
$image = $request->file('image');
$filename = time() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalName();
$path = '/images/projects/' . $project->name . '/';
if(!File::exists($path)) {
// path does not exist
File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true);
}

$location = public_path() . $path . $filename; 

Image::make($image)->resize(640, 425)->save($location);

$project->image = $path . $filename;
}


$project->save();

//redirect to the view
//return redirect()->route('project.show', $project->id);
return redirect()->route('project.index');



}
```

Comment: Check your folder permission...

Comment: I have already checked it and updated from 755 to 777. But no luck

Comment: make sure all sub directories also carry the same permissions.

Comment: As you may noticed in the code the folders are creating dynamically and and I have already set permission with 777.
$path = '/images/projects/' . $project->name . '/';
if(!File::exists($path)) {
// path does not exist
File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true);
}